# How to get the duration time in Python?

Tags: python, time

See my sample code:

```
import time

start_time_string = "2013-05-24 17:51:06"
end_time_string = "2013-05-24 17:59:33"

start_time_stamp = time.mktime(time.strptime(start_time_string, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
start_time_struct = time.localtime(start_time_stamp)

end_time_stamp = time.mktime(time.strptime(end_time_string, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
end_time_struct = time.localtime(end_time_stamp)

# what's the next step to get duration time, like x minute?
```

I read https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html but don't find a method.

Thank you!

This question is closed, thanks so much to pjz and Robᵩ!

A perfect solution is posted in http://ideone.com/J8VwNl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module, not the `time` module.